# use remote desktop on ubuntu 18.10 (not xbuntu or xfce)

Tags: remote, rdp

I'm trying to use the "Remmina Remote Desktop" application that came with my Ubuntu 18.10 (64 bit) install to connect to another ubuntu desktop. But anytime, I try to connect, then automatic it's login to xface flavor.
I want to default login on unity

Comment: what if you login physically to the unity (actually it's called gnome-ubuntu now) session on that computer first? that should make it default. Also are you making sure to login in VNC not RDP mode?

Comment: yes I am sure to login RDP mode

Comment: I said to do VNC.

Comment: no cause I want to login from another network. that's why I can't use VNC

Comment: ok can you try the other thing I suggested?

Comment: yes. when I tried to physically then it comes unity session but when i tried to RDP it's not working